# Correlation Coefficients between population and suicide in Rstudio

Tags: r, correlation

#### Percentage Change

```
selectedCountry <- dataset %>%
  filter(country == 'Japan') %>%
  select(population, suicides_no, year) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(s_count = sum(suicides_no), p_count = sum(population))

   year s_count   p_count
  <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
1  1979   20711 107268500
2  1980   20416 108473500
3  1981   19976 109674700
4  1982   20535 110722900
5  1983   24853 111070000
6  1984   24221 111950000
```

I want to find the correlation between population and suicide after I aggregate population and suicide like this

```
percentage <- selectedCountry %>%
  arrange(year) %>%
  mutate(pct.chg.s = 100 * (s_count - lag(s_count,default=first(s_count))) / lag(s_count,default=first(s_count))) %>%
  mutate(pct.chg.p = 100 * (p_count - lag(p_count,default=first(p_count))) / lag(p_count,default=first(p_count))) %>%
  mutate(correlation = cor(pct.chg.s, pct.chg.p))

head(percentage)
```

I end up with a result

```
   year s_count   p_count pct.chg.s pct.chg.p correlation
  <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
1  1979   20711 107268500      0        0         0.00789
2  1980   20416 108473500     -1.42     1.12      0.00789
3  1981   19976 109674700     -2.16     1.11      0.00789
4  1982   20535 110722900      2.80     0.956     0.00789
5  1983   24853 111070000     21.0      0.313     0.00789
6  1984   24221 111950000     -2.54     0.792     0.00789
```

to plot the corr between two variables using two way (I can't sure if this true or false)

[image]

```
ggscatter(percentage, x = "pct.chg.s", y = "pct.chg.p",
          add = "reg.line", conf.int = TRUE,
          cor.coef = TRUE, cor.method = "pearson",
          xlab = "Percentage Change in Suicide",
          ylab = "Percentage Change in Population",
          color = "blue", shape = 19,
          palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
          ellipse = TRUE, mean.point = TRUE,
          star.plot = TRUE)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(percentage, aes(x = pct.chg.p, y = pct.chg.s)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",formula = y ~ x) + 
  labs(title = "Correlation between Pubulation and Suicides", 
       x = "Percentage Change in Suicide", 
       y = "Percentage Change in Population")
```

Comment: I don't understand what the question is.  You aggregate your data to the yearly level and then calculate a correlation of 0.00789.  So that's the correlation...

Comment: @DanY  the correlation is the same for all rows.

Comment: That's right.  Correlation is a single value calculated from two vectors of values.  It's a bit like how an average is a single value calculated from one vector of values.  Why you want to store that one value in every row of your dataset is beyond me.

Comment: @DanY I want to see if there is a relationship between the number of population and suicides, I end up with two graphs if any one of them is the right one. Thank you for your eplay

Comment: There's no such thing as the "right" graph.  If you want to assess whether there is a *linear* relationship between two variables, then correlation or simple regression are good starting points.  Both correlation and simple regression can be used to assess whether there is a linear relationship between X and Y.  Usually, a plot of X vs Y is considered when using either of these statistics/methods.  (Note that you ask about the measures themselves (e.g., population), but in your scatterplot, you plot percent changes.)